# Want to get all values of specific spans in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have severals span in my page and i want to get each of them and display the value of each span in my javascript console for example.

Here my example of my code:

```
<div id="les-articles-du-panier">
<span id="mon-panier-qte-1">36</span>
<span id="mon-panier-qte-3">26</span>
<span id="mon-panier-qte-4">8</span>
<span id="mon-panier-qte-5">12</span>
</div>
```

And for each mon-panier-qte- i wnt to do a console.log(titi);

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

> And for each **mon-panier-qte-** i wnt to do a console.log(titi);

Like this:

```
$('#les-articles-du-panier span[id^="mon-panier-qte"]').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text()); // or whatever
});
```

If the spans always appear directly below main div, you can use immediate childern selector `>`:

```
$('#les-articles-du-panier > span[id^="mon-panier-qte"]').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text()); // or whatever
});
```

If all spans inside `#les-articles-du-panier` are only those having id starting with `mon-panier-qte`, you can skip that:

```
$('#les-articles-du-panier span').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text()); // or whatever
});
```

Comment: @superscral: You would use `$(this).text()` then.

Comment: Great !
And a last question,
if I want, for each div "ma-div-xxx", to get all spans where id is mon-panier-qte-xxx and mon-panier-mt-xxx
Thx !!

Comment: @superscral: You would replace them accordingly as shown above.

Comment: i have tried but not working :
    $('div[id^="mon-produit"]').each(function(){
    console.log("id de la chaque div = " + this.id); // or whatever
    console.log ( ('#mon-panier-qte-' + this.id).text() ); //not working !

  });

not working :(

Comment: @superscral: Create your example at jsbin.com so that we can better understand what exactly you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`span` elements don't have values, but assuming you mean their text content: If you just want the ones within `les-articles-du-panier`:

```
$("#les-articles-du-panier > span").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

That selects the elements, then loops over them with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each).

The selector will match only `span` elements that are immediate children of the element with the ID "les-articles-du-panier". If you want *all* descendants (including children of children, etc.), leave out the `>` and just use `$("#les-articles-du-panier span")...`.

If you really just want to select the "mon-panier-qte-*" elements, you can use an [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector instead:

```
$('span[id^="mon-panier-qte-"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Or you can even combine them, to match *only* "mon-panier-qte-*" elements that are direct children of "les-articles-du-panier":

```
$('#les-articles-du-panier > span[id^="mon-panier-qte-"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

...or descendants (just dropping the `>`):

```
$('#les-articles-du-panier span[id^="mon-panier-qte-"]').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

You get the idea. Worth reading up on selectors [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: The issue is that in the div les-article-du-apnier i have undread of other span like span id="tutu" ... ;)

Comment: @superscral: I've updated to show an alternative just for those. Sorry, missed the line at the end of your question at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('span[id^="mon-panier-qte"]').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

This will log all of your "values" of every span in your HTML Page. You have to know that a span has no value it can only contain text. Which you get with the method `.text()` But be aware that if you have some html code in your span .text() strips every html content of that and only returns pure text. Additionally you could specify which class you span should contain and so on. For that take a look at Selectors ;-)

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Take a look at the `.each()` documentation of jQuery. There is explained what .each() does and what its good for:

- http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: The issue is that in the div les-article-du-apnier i have undread of other span like span id="tutu" ... ;)

Comment: yeah but by specifying that you only what spans with the id's that start "mon-panier-qte" like in my answer all the tutu will be ignored ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery("#les-articles-du-panier").children().each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text());          
});
```

Comment: thats not the answer, he does not want to have every children of the div he only wants the spans which start with mon-panier-qte !